# c# HttpClient Patch request with Body?

Tags: c#, .net, api, patch

I'm trying to send a request using http client. I need to add the body to the request and pass in parameters. I have some code based on http request but its not working currently:

```
httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
                var value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
                var content = new StringContent(value, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                **var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("PATCH"), url + value);**
                var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
                string Path = response.RequestMessage.RequestUri.AbsolutePath.ToString();
                Success = response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
```

My issue is in the bold part of code. I need to be able to pass in that body portion some how to the request.

Current response:
{StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 29 Mar 2022 18:22:37 GMT
Server:
}}

So far not been able to find working code snippets for PATCH with body. I've even tried just doing a POST.

I've also tried this:

```
//httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
                //httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                //httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                //var s = new JsonSerializerSettings { DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat };
                //var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, s);
                //var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("PATCH"), url);
                //request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                //var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
                //var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                //string Path = response.RequestMessage.RequestUri.AbsolutePath.ToString();
```

However, I noticed I ran into the same issue here as before. Its not adding the body to the request. I nuild it but never pass the body. So I need to pass the body in the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is set the `Content` property of the `HttpRequestMessage`:

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Patch, url) {
    Content = new StringContent(value, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
};
```